# Flutter - Textfield reaction when focus changes

Tags: flutter

I've made a program where the user can create an account, but I've placed some restrictions on the textfields (like for the First Name, it can only accept a string made of A-Z or a-z).

I want an "error text" to show under the textfield if the input is wrong (like if the user types "John1"), but I don't know how to do this. The simple way would be to use the **onEditingComplete** but this only works if the user taps on the keyboard the "done" key.

Is there a way to make the "error text" appear when the focus changes from one textfield to another?

Comment: what about `TextFormField.validator`?

Comment: validator doesn't seem to be working, here's my val: `validator: (value) {
            return isAlpha(value) ? null : widget.errorString;
          },` @pskink

Comment: flutter does not have `isAlpha` function so i dont know what it is doing - most likely your `isAlpha` method does not work as expected

Comment: @pskink it's a package that checks if the string is Alpha (A-Z, a-z) and returns a bool

Comment: `validator: (value) { var res = isAlpha(value); print('[$value] => $res'); return res? null : widget.errorString; }` what dou you see on the logs?

Comment: @pskink I don't know why but it isn't printing anything

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation

Answer (score 0):

You can use the validator property of the textfield to do this. It is recommended to encapsulate your fields in a `Form()` widget and then use the `FormTextField()` widget to implement your validations, this will enable an error to be shown at the bottom of the text field, if focus changes, or submission is attempted.

Example:

```
TextFormField(
  onSaved: (String value) {},
  validator: (String value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
     return 'Please enter some text';
    }
    return null;
  },
)
```

The error will appear below in red fonts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show error text whenever text/value changed you can do this.

In TextField 'onChanged' validate the user input using some regex and check for error ,if there is an error using TextField decoration 'errorText' property you can show required error.

```
 Widget phoneNumberTextField() {
return Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 10, 25, 10),
  child: TextField(
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    controller: _phoneNumberController,
    maxLength: Constants.PhoneNumberTextFieldMaxLength,
    onChanged: (value) {
      _phoneNumberErrorText =
          validatePhoneNumberTextField(_phoneNumberController.text);
      _hasPhoneNumberError = _phoneNumberErrorText.isNotEmpty;
      setState(() {});
    },
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 1.0),
        ),
        errorText: _hasPhoneNumberError ? _phoneNumberErrorText : null),
  ),
);
```

}

```
String validatePhoneNumberTextField(String text) {
String errorText = '';
if (text.length < 1) {
  errorText = 'Phone Number should not be empty';
} else if (text.length != 10) {
  errorText = 'Please enter valid phone number.';
}
return errorText;
```

}